# Write/Read struct array data table C++

Tags: c++, file, struct

Im fairly new to c++ and I've spent about six hours on this, sadly with no result.

im trying to do the following. (for my own practice)

1. Make a navigation menu like in cmd. #done
2. Create two structs with the concept of "uml aggregation" #done
3. Make function for input, output, sort by a value, etc. #done
4. Write everything to a file #Struggling from this point.
5. Read back from the file.
6. Use the data later(sort by name, delete last object, add new...etc)

I have a massive code that I think will be silly to post (and a waste of time) so I'll just post a simpler version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct man{
char name[20];
int age;

};

struct group{
man* men[3];
};

void fill( man &y);
void show( man &y);
void input(group &x, man &y);
void output(group &x, man &y);

int main(){
    man q;
    group w;

    input(w, q);
    cout<<endl;
    output(w, q);

    ofstream w1file("B.dat");
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        w1file.write((char*) &w.men[i]->name, 20);
        w1file.write((char*) &w.men[i]->age, sizeof(int));
    }
    w1file.close();

    ifstream r1file("B.dat");

    while(r1file.good()){
        r1file.read((char*) &w.men[0]->name, 20);
        r1file.read((char*) &w.men[0]->age,  sizeof(int));
        r1file.read((char*) &w.men[1]->name, 20);
        r1file.read((char*) &w.men[1]->age,  sizeof(int));
    }
    output(w, q);
    r1file.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

    void fill( man &y){
        gets(y.name);
        cin>>y.age;
        cin.ignore();
    }    
void show( man &y){
    cout<<y.name<<endl;
    cout<<y.age<<endl;
}
void input(group &x, man &y){
    x.men[2]= new man[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2;i++){
        fill(y);;
        x.men[i]= new man(y);
    }
}
void output(group &x, man &y){
    for (int i=0; i<2;i++){
        show(*x.men[i]);
    }
}
```

if i remove the writing part, then the program just crashes as soon as i press run.
ive tried it like this, and with file>>"variable"... ive tried it with only first element...tried to copy the whole thing to an array, write the array and then read it,  but nothing works :(

I also want it to output the data in the file like this: (example)

```
#in the txt, dat, whatever
John 21
Pier 18...etc
```

So i can edit the data directly from the written file.
but what im getting is this:

```
John н@     А…J {   Adam ed н@     А…J Х
```

My initial idea was to make a program that outputs data to files in the form of tables(hope you understand me) 
exmpl.

```
name1 age1 wage1 married/not married1
name2 age2 wage2 married/not married2
name3...age3...etc
```

Can someone from heaven please help me with this and if possible explain what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i; i<2; i++){
```

Looks at this line, until you see the problem. Keep looking at it, until you do.

Hint: what do you expect the first value of `i` to be, in this loop?

P.S.: Why are you allocating a single instance of `man`, for men[0] and men[1], and two instances of `man`, for men[2]?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo

Comment: If that was a typo, your attempt to produce a [mcve] was commendable, but it ultimately failed. Before you waste everyone's time, please verify that the code sample you posted compiles, and demonstrates your problem. Don't just assume it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

The writing for uses an uninitialized variable i, so that it starts with an undetermined value.  Try :

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){   //i=0 !!
```

Then you write binary data in a file open in the default text mode. This can, depending on the binary value and the operating system alter what is effectively written in the file.  So:

```
ofstream w1file("B.dat", ios::binary);  // binary mode instead of text mode
```

The same applies of course to the reading stream.

Note that you could have from 0 to 3 men in the group.  It would be wise to write at the beginning of the group the number of items.  So when reading the group you could first read the number of items to be expected and loop until you have read them all.  Your current reading loop is weird, as it will read the file and constantly overwrite the 2 first mens (if there are more data in the file).

The way you could properly read would be:

```
 const int maxmen=3;  
 for (int i=0; i<maxmen && r1file.read((char*) &w.men[i]->name, 20)
                   && r1file.read((char*) &w.men[0]->age, sizeof(int)); i++)
    cout << "Successfuly read item "<<i<<endl; 
 }
```

Note also that this code is heavily leaking memory.

Comment: If I use the ios::binary, will it write to b.dat in binary?

Comment: Could you possibly show an example of how to make a proper loop to read through many items? I have absolutely no idea of how to do that. And do i need to allocate new memory when I read in the items? Since I have an array of man pointers.  And is therr another, more efficient and simpler way to read /write from file?

Comment: @Muhammedbakijev If you use `write()`/`read()` as you do, it will write and read binay data regardless of the open mode.  But the text mode might alter the binary data you wrtie/read (for example on windows, it would transform the binary value of 10 into 13 followed by 10 at writing).

Comment: Why is the w.men[].age 0? Shouldn't it also loop through like men[].name?